# Checking for presence of same value against all instances of a reference ID

Tags: string, amazon-redshift, matching

I have a table which is a list of orders, which contains suborders and statuses against each of them. A sample table would look like this

| Order ID | Sub order ID | Order Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A1 | Delivered |
| 1 | B1 | Out for Delivery |
| 2 | A2 | Delivered |
| 2 | B2 | Cancelled |

Now, I want to check for orders, where all sub orders are in Delivered status. How would I write such a query in Postgresql?

I have tried using a LISTAGG, but I'm able to only get orders at least one of the orders is Delivered.

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Comment: There is no `listagg()` function in Postgres - it's `string_agg()`

Answer (score 0):

Your data sample doesn't show a case where all suborders are delivered. But anyway, a kind of hacky way to do it would be to group by `OrderID` and select groups where `max(OrderStatus) = min(OrderStatus) and max(OrderStatus) = 'Delivered'`

```
select OrderID
from table_name
group by OrderID
having max(OrderStatus) = min(OrderStatus) and max(OrderStatus) = 'Delivered'
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=1820b0a6ab873c55b6eb8ca430fe5d9b)